# Mathjax in Ipython notebook fails for fairly large equations

Tags: jupyter-notebook, mathjax

For very large equations generated by sympy, mathjax in the ipython notebook sometimes fails to render the equation.  Instead, it shows the latex source of the equation in a box (which stretches far off the page).  I can copy and paste that source into a real latex document, and it renders just fine (though I might have to use the `geometry` package to make the output PDF extraordinarily wide).

I've actually successfully rendered longer equations, but these particular ones I found were long and also had very large numbers of `\left` `\right` pairs in them.  I'm not sure if that has anything to do with the failure, but it seems relevant.

What is going on?  How can I debug mathjax?  And how can I get it to render those equations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the debugging tip found in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17177527/1194883), I found that the buffer was too small, which led me to [this mathjax page](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/options/TeX.html), where I found the solution.  After I increase mathjax's `MAXBUFFER` value, the equations render just fine.  To do this (and turn debugging on), I just put the following in my `~/.ipython/profile_default/static/custom/custom.js`.

```
MathJax.Hub.Config({
  TeX: {
    noErrors: {disabled: true}, // Show error messages
    MAXBUFFER: 25*1024, // Set size of buffer in bytes
  },
});
```

[Note: Your profile may be elsewhere.  To find it, run `ipython profile locate`.  If you don't have the `custom.js` file or its directories, you may need to create them.]